# Android : Image button has unwanted margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I have some image buttons in my android project. but they have some gray margins like this pic(I take this pic from real device):

[image]

How can I remove them??
I used this code but it doesn't have any effect.

```
 ib.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Image buttons just defined in java and I don't have them on xml.

```
 ib = new ImageButton(this);
 ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
 ib.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
 ib.setLayoutParams(ibrllp);
```

How can I remove this additional gray margin?

Comment: Where do you see them? I mean... **grey** margins?!

Comment: use your on style for button and set margin as 0.

Comment: set Image Button background null.  ib.setBackground(null);

Comment: @DerGolem it's around my image button.

Comment: thank you all....  ib.setBackground(null); is worked for me ...

Comment: setAdjustViewBounds has nothing to do with that 'margins', it's used to make button's aspect ratio the same as drawable's.  What is the size of button ? What's in the ibrllp ?

Comment: Also you can use ImageView instead ImageButton

Comment: @Dima I want to use it as a button

Comment: Do you mean the **shadow**? By the way, an ImageView (and also a TextView) **can be used as a Button**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your image button background is null. eg.

```
ib.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it has a background with a margin.

In code:

```
ImageButton imageButton = ImageButton.class.cast(rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton));
imageButton.setBackground(null);
```

In xml file:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@null" />
```

"rootView" is the layout inflated to fragment or activity.